# Opening a sharepoint document with WordViewer.aspx such that it moves to the end of the document

Tags: sharepoint

My users would like their sharepoint documents to open to the end of the document when they click on the document name.  The documents are not checked out in this case.  They are viewed in the browser using WordViewer.aspx. 
I'm hoping there is a simple parameter I can pass to WordViewer.aspx that will cause it to automatically move to the end of the file?